# Select both options under Universal Windows App Development Tools for 7" Windows 10 tablet apps development?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm insterested in developing an app for a 7" tablet running `Windows 10`, so I'm installing the necessary components in VS2015.

I did notice that there are two options to choose from under **Universal Windows App Development Tools**:

- Tools (1.2) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)
- WIndows 10 SDK (10.0.10240)

Should I install both of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up selecting both options, but thanks for all the feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

I think Tools (1.2) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586) is enough, but if you install WIndows 10 SDK (10.0.10240), you will be able to set the MinVersion of the targeted Windows 10 application you develop to it. However, I am still a newbie in Windows 10 Mobile development.